# SSH connection closes when entering password for repository I try to clone using git

Tags: ssh, debian, git

I have a private repository that I store on Bitbucket, that I would like to clone to my Debian server. While I am SSH connected to the server, normally I would run:

```
git clone https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo.git
```

Which then responds:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
Password for 'https://myusername@bitbucket.org':
```

Normally I would simply enter my password and it would work, but now whenever I start entering my password (without even hitting enter), I get the message:

```
Connection to myserverip closed.
```

and my SSH session is terminated.

Cloning non-password protected repositories still works and this problem just started recently. What should I look into in order to fix this problem?

---

I also tried entering the clone command from my local shell:

```
ssh user@myserverip "git clone https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo.git"
```

but I get a similar problem:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myusername@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
```

Cloning from Bitbucket to my local machine (with the same repository) works fine.

Comment: do the firewall rules on your server allow outgoing connections?

Comment: @MichaelColeman Yes. Also, cloning non-password protected repositories works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to BitBucket support.

Comment: @fukawi2 Why should this question be aimed at Bitbucket support? I gave Bitbucket as an example of a place I might clone a repo from that would ask me for a password. I have no trouble cloning repos from Bitbucket on my local machine. Also, the message `Connection to myserverip closed.` is about the SSH connection from my local machine to my Debian server being disconnected. If it were a Bitbucket problem, then git would fail and emit an error message, rather than the SSH session between my local machine and my server.

Comment: @dg123 Ah, I see now. Apologies. You should edit your question to make that fact clearer that it's your SSH session to your server that is being terminated (not the connection from your server to BitBucket). I have retracted my close vote.